# Powershell Compare string to folders

Tags: powershell, contains

I am completely new to Powershell and I want to know if a language code is contained on a folder list. I am using this little script.

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned -Scope CurrentUser
$path = "C:\Projects\Eg_Proyect\2022_834"
$lang = "DE-DE"
$Lsta2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Name
$Lsta2 
$Lsta2.Count
$Lsta2 -contains $lang
```

The result is:

```
0_SOURCE
10_EN-GB_PL
11_EN-GB_CS
12_EN-GB_DE-DE
13_EN-GB_TR
1_EN-GB_ES-ES
2__
3_EN-GB_IT-IT
4_EN-GB_IT-IT
5_EN-GB_HU
6_EN-GB_HU
7_EN-GB_NL-NL
8_EN-GB_NL-NL
9_EN-GB_PT-PT
14
**False**
```

Why it does not return True?

Comment: That's because `-contains` is looking for an exact complete match in an array (case insensitive).

Comment: So I should parse each item on the output list? Or exists a direct way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always confusion about the **string** method `.Contains()` which looks to find a certain substring withing another string and the PowerShell `-contains` operator, which looks for a complete, exact (case-insensitive) item in an **array**.

Since in your case you have an array of strings, you could use:

```
[bool]($Lsta2 -match 'DE-DE')    # uses RegEx. returns True or False because of the cast to `[bool]`
```

OR

```
[bool]($Lsta2 -like '*DE-DE*')  # uses WildCards ('*' and/or '?')
```

OR use the `.Contains()` string operator on every string individually. This is of course a waste of time, AND it works Case-Sensitively, but to show that it can be done:

```
[bool]($Lsta2 | ForEach-Object { if ($_.Contains('DE-DE')) { $true }})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-match` to search with a regex in a string

```
$Lsta2 -match $lang
```